# vuex ajax call and several components

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'd like to know whats the best practice for an ajax call with vuex and multiple components sharing the data from this call.

Do I store a loading, success and error property for that call in the store so it populates all the way through to the components?  I'm not sure whats the best way.  I also don't want to call the ajax from all the components since that defeats the purpose of having it called once.

Right now I'm storing as I mentioned above:

```
new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        persons: {
             data: null,
             loading: false,
             error: null
        }
    }
});
```

I do this for EACH api call and then I store it there. Any better ways?

Answer (score 5):

[This article](https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/08/28/vue-js-ajax-recipes/) describes a few patterns for implementing ajax calls and updating vuex state. Personally I agree with the author that method 3 of moving your ajax calls to the vuex store as actions because, as the article points out, it decouples state and presentation logic. This is also helpful because you can return a promise from your action to know when the state can be mutated

Code example from the article:

```
store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        message: ''
    },
    mutations: {
        updateMessage(state, payload) {
            state.message = payload
        }
    },
    actions: {
        refreshMessage(context) {
            return new Promise((resolve) => {
                this.$http.get('...').then((response) => {
                    context.commit('updateMessage', response.data.message);
                    resolve();
                });
            });
        }
    }
});

Vue.component('my-component', {
    template: '<div>{{ message }}</div>',
    methods: {
        refreshMessage() {
            this.$store.dispatch('refeshMessage').then(() => {
            // do stuff
        });
        }
    },
    computed: {
        message: { return this.$store.state.message; }
    }
});
```

So as you can see here, ajax calls are encapsulated as vuex actions. In a component that relies on data from an ajax call, the component can perform the action (this.$store.dispatch('refreshMessage').then...) which will make the ajax call and update the data in the store. Since your component already has a reactive property that depends on data from the store, it will update automatically once the store has new data.